# Store big number in Oracle -- Please give an example that can store 9e125

Tags: oracle

The Oracle doc says one can store a number up to 9.99...9 x 10125 with up to 38 significant digits: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#i16209.

I tried this:

```
create table bigtest (t number(38,2));
insert into bigtest values (5e40);
```

But I got

```
[Error] Execution (8: 29): ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column
```

It is supposed to be able to store 9.99e125, right? Could any one give an example on how to store 9.99e125?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use the `number` data type without precision and scale specified.

You **can** specify precision and scale for very large (and also for very small) numbers though. Just keep in mind that *negative* scale means "that many zeros at the **end** of an integer" - the **total** number of digits can be up to *precision* + **absolute value** of *scale*.

In the example below, note that 38 + 84 = 122. The scale must be between -84 and 127, which means that if you do use precision and scale, you can only store numbers < 1e123 - a smaller range than for the full `number` data type, but still storing very large numbers

```
create table tbl(x number(38,-84));

insert into tbl values (3.493e121);

select x from tbl;

         X
----------
3.4930E+121
```

Answer (score 2):

See DBfiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f8c7ad51630b2f0139291c26f3b4d87c) (Oracle 18c).

```
create table T1 (
  anumber number
) ;

insert into t1 ( anumber ) values ( 9.99e125 ) ;

select * from t1 ;

ANUMBER
999000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Comment: Indeed @PaulZWu but notice the manual *"Oracle guarantees portability of numbers with a precision equal to or less than 38 digits."* *"When you specify numeric fields, it is a good idea to specify the precision and scale. This provides extra integrity checking on input."* it almost sounds like Oracle Corp disadvice to use `NUMBER` without precision and scale